# using recursive to compute fibonalci sequence (mips code)

Tags: recursion, mips

i have this c code for fibonalcci sequence using recursive:

```
int fib(int n)
{
if (n==0) return 0;
if (n==1) return 1;
else return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

and i want to translate that c code into mips code (register a0 contain the value of n and register s0 contain the value of fib(n) )
here is what i have done:

```
F: bne $a0,$zero,L
addi $s0,$zero,0
addi $s1,$zero,1
jr $ra
L: addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)
addi $a0,$a0,-1
jal F
addi $t0,$s1,0
add $s1,$s0,$s1
addi $s0,$t0,0
lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra
```

but it seem not do exactly what the c code do and i want to fix the mips code to let it do exactly like the c code. How do i fix that mips code?

Comment: It would help if you included _all_ the code for the assembly function. Right now it seems to be missing the `F` label and some argument checks at the beginning.

Comment: sorry Michael i have already fixed it.